# Setting Itemsource for ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have created an AutocompleteBox and it works completely fine outside a ControlTemplate. When I place it within a Control template, the autocompletebox is no longer populated with any items.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditAppointmentTemplate" TargetType="telerik:SchedulerDialog">
    <Grid Margin="6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="97" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Participants" Margin="6 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Margin="6 0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Atts}" 
                                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedAttendees,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" 
                                    TextSearchPath="Search" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource MultiAutoBox}" 
                                    WatermarkContent="Search ..." 
                                    MinHeight="55" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Padding="5">
        </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="EditAppointmentDialogStyle" TargetType="telerik:SchedulerDialog">
     ....
     <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditAppointmentTemplate}" />
     ....
<Style x:Key="EditAppointmentDialogStyle"/>

<telerik:RadScheduleView x:Name="scheduleview" ....
                         EditAppointmentDialogStyle="{StaticResource EditAppointmentDialogStyle}"
                         ....
 <telerik:RadScheduleView x:Name="scheduleview"/>
```

I'm thinking I have to set the ItemsSource to target a relative ancestor
I tried the following and the itemsource isn't populating still.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:SchedulerDialog}}, Path=Atts}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control templates should be entirely self contained, as such your control should expose a dependency property (call it `SuggestionsSource` for example) to which the auto-complete box binds via a `TemplateBinding`.

Where you use the dialog control you then bind said property to your `DataContext` property.

---

In your dialogue class (if you want to extend the functionality of an existing control you will need a sub-class to introduce properties, here `MySchedulerDialog`)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SuggestionsSourceProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("SuggestionsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(MySchedulerDialog), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
public IList SuggestionsSource
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(SuggestionsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SuggestionsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

In control template XAML:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Margin="6 0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SuggestionsSource}" ...>
```

Where you use the control:

```
<local:MySchedulerDialog SuggestionsSource="{Bindings Atts}" .../>
```

Comment: Could you possibly give me a snippet or PseudoCode so I can have a more indepth understand what you are referring to?

Comment: @Master: You really should read up on control authoring on MSDN, added example anyway...